# Are different certificates used automatically

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I'm building an app that uses Parse to send push notifications. Currently I am in beta and have uploaded both a development and production push certificates. Client side, I add a bool to the Installation object to designate if the client is running a beta version.

When I send a push notification with Cloud Code how do I specify which certificate to use? Is it automatically selected for me? What happens when my app is in production simultaneously with my beta?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Parse, but I found this in [their tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) :

> Note that once you have uploaded a production push certificate to Parse, **you will only be able to target devices using a distribution provisioning profile**. Devices running an app signed with a development provisioning profile will need to install the newly provisioned build again.

Based on this quote, you can't use Parse simultaneously for both development and production push notifications.